# How can I synchronize a collison particle with a shockwave

Tags: particles

I am working on a spaceship shield project. I have created the shield, and am using particles to simulate the laser fire. I have added a collision modifier to the shield so the laser effect dies on contact. Now, I have created a shockwave in Adobe After Effects and saved it as a .tga animation. I want to synch the laser impact with the shockwave so that every time a laser hits the shield, the shockwave appears and starts exactly where the laser particle died. How can I set this up as I am looking at multiple laser hits on the shields. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hello everyone since I posted this question I changed the shockwave from an After effects file to a Blender shockwave. So my question is the same, how do I have the shockwave appear at the point of impact between the laser and the shield other than me doing it manually and adding the key frames?